# How to Read Multiple Files from a Folder in ADLS Gen2 using Pyspark in Azure Synapse and use for Processing?

Tags: pyspark, azure-databricks, azure-synapse, azure-data-lake-gen2

I am Looking for an solution where i want to read all the files from a folder Name as
**`'COUNTRIES DETAIL'` containing another folder **`'YEAR'`** which is there in  a Container in ADLS GEN2 name **`'DETAILS'`**.
. Currently i have 200 files in my sub folder 'YEAR'. the format of files are `'YYYY_DETAILS_GERMANY_GERMAN_.csv' , 'YYYY_DETAILS_INDIA_GOOD_.csv', 'YYYY_DETAILS_ENGLAND_PRODUCTS_.csv'`.

I am looking for a approach through which i can read all the files from the Folder and use that file only which is required for transformations.
The Scenario i want to create is once i read the files from the folder, i want to pick only that file which is required for operations.

**HOW WE SHOULD PICK THE FILE OR WHICH FILE TO PICK??**

I am reading an file already from another folder and stored that data in dataframe df . The dataframe have a column called 'COUNTRY_NAME'. There will be common value in 'COUNTRY_NAME' column in the dataframe. Suppose we have value as 'INDIAGOOD' in COUNTRY_NAME Column so i need to pick 'YYYY_DETAILS_INDIA_GOOD_.csv' file data and load into my another Dataframe . simlilarly for other cases i need to implement this same scenario. if the value in COUNTRY_NAME column matches with the filename present in adls i want to load that file data into dataframe and do operations. There will always be common value in COUNTRY_NAME Column which have some matching Text with the file that is there in 'YEAR FOLDER'

SAMPLE DATAFRAME 1

```
+-----------+
COUNTRY_NAME|
+-----------+
INDIAGOOD    
INDIAGOOD
INDIAGOOD
INDIAGOOD
```

FILENAMES IN ADLS

```
 +---------------------------------+
 FILE_NAMES                        |
 +---------------------------------+
 YYYY_DETAILS_INDIA_GOOD_.csv      |
 YYYY_DETAILS_ENGLAND_PRODUCTS_.csv|
 YYYY_DETAILS_GERMANY_GERMAN_.csv  |
```

As we have value 'INDIAGOOD' in my column value 'COUNTRY_NAME' i will pick file YYYY_DETAILS_INDIA_GOOD_.csv from the adls because its substring matching with filename in adls and load it into my dataframe df2

Comment: Could you please add your folder structure and sample expected result?

Comment: I see that the file name is like `YYYY_DETAILS_INDIA_GOOD_.csv` and dataframe has the value as `INDIAGOOD`. Is this the case for all the column values i.e., no underscores in column values but there are underscores in file names?

Comment: Can you edit the question provide the sample column values as well?

Comment: There can also be a value like `ENGLANDPRODUCTS` in the filename dataframe. Is this right?

Comment: Understood, and you want to load all data from those matching filenames to same dataframe. Is this right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249885/discussion-between-saideep-arikontham-and-bigdata-lover).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- I have the following files in my ADLS folder.

[image]

- And I have a Dataframe called `files_df` with the following values:

[image]

- Now the requirement is to check if the filename exists in the above dataframe column value. If it is present, then load the corresponding file's data (from ADLS) to a dataframe called `final_df`.
- To do this I have used the following code. First, I have used `dbutils.fs.ls()` to get list of contents in the year folder:

```
files_in_adls = dbutils.fs.ls("abfss://data@dataalk2511.dfs.core.windows.net/Countries detail/year")
print(files_in_adls)
```

[image]

- Then I have used the following code with loop to check if the file actually exists in the column and then load its data to `final_df` using union.

```
#initialising the final dataframe
final_df = None   

#looping through files
for file in files_in_adls:
    req = ''.join(file.name.split('_')[2:-1])
    #print(req) 
    #gives us required filenames like if filename if YYYY_DETAILS_INDIA_GOOD_.csv then the value of req in that case would be INDIAGOOD


    if(files_df.filter(files_df.filenames.contains(req.upper())).count()>0):  #checking if this extracted name is present in files_df column values

        #reading data
        if(final_df is not None):  
            df = spark.read.option("header",True).format('csv').load(file.path)
            final_df = final_df.union(df)
        else:
            final_df = spark.read.option("header",True).format('csv').load(file.path)
    else:
        print(f"{req} is not present in ADLS")
        
#display(final_df)
```

[image]

**Note:**
Here, my file data has only one row like `this is from <file name> file`. Since there are 2 matching files, both of their data is loaded into same dataframe(final_df).

Comment: Updated the answer with modified code (if condition).